# Various linking issues when adding VCLFixPack.pas

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

When adding *VCLFixPack.pas* (latest as of 2013-09-27) to my projects I get strange linking errors for some of them. Some compile fine, but for some it complains about not finding *TYPES.OBJ* or *DBGRIDS.OBJ* etc when linking.

Any idea what the issue is?

VCLFixPack is found here

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the path to the delphi lib files from your link line.

If memory serves, for 2010 you needed $(BDS)\lib and $(BDS)\lib\release in your linker paths

(Project->Options->Paths and Directories->Library Paths)

Comment: Those are in place. It's strange that most projects compile fine with VCLFixPack added but a few gives these strange linking errors (which goes away if VCLFixPack is removed from the project).